# does the order of multiple or in query affect the relevance?

Tags: mysql

given the tables:

items(id)

tags(id,name,text)

itemtags(itemid,tagid)

```
select id 
  from items t1
  join itemstags t2 
    on t1.id = t2.itemid
  join tags t3 
    on t2.tagid = t3.id 
 where t3.name = '$tag' 
    or t3.name like '%$tag%' 
    or t3.text like '%$tag%'
```

when searching tag= man

I see mixed results of items tagged :

man, command ,manual, superman, many...

my question is how can I show the most relevant items ie those tagged "man"  first and the irrelevant ones after.

Comment: You will have to define what is 'relevant', and what not before you can do that.

Comment: @Luuk I will search some more on how to define relevance.

Comment: `FULLTEXT` search may help you solve this problem. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: If `t3.name = '$tag'` is true, `t3.name like '%$tag%'` is also true, so you can omit `t3.name = '$tag'`. And as a side note: You should better use parameterized queries.

Comment: To answer your question: no, the order of clauses in the `where` clause does not affect the sorting of the final output. Filtering and sorting are orthogonal operations, and you don't get any sorting unless you ask for it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of the conditions in the `where` clause:

```
t3.name = '$tag' or t3.name like '%$tag%' or t3.text like '%$tag%'
```

defines the *relevance* then you can use conditional sorting like this:

```
order by t3.name = '$tag' desc,
         t3.name like '%$tag%' desc,
         t3.text like '%$tag%' desc
```

so the most *relevant* rows appear first.

Actually you can omit the last part: `t3.text like '%$tag%' desc` since these 3 cases are the only cases that exist in the results and if a row does not satisfy any of the first 2 conditions it is certain that it will be sorted with the last group.

Comment: thank you very much. this is what I wanted, I didn't know you can order by the condition.

Comment: there is a problem though, same query does not give the same order (among the relevants) so using this query in pages will cause an item to appear in page 1 and page 2. how is this possible?

Comment: The order by clause does not affect the number of the rows that you get, only their order.

Comment: yes I know, but it seems the results are random (they are indeed tagged "man" ) but each time the query gives a different order. in my php I add to the query ``limit $start, 24`` however it will not be productive since there is the possibility the results of the next page will contain the results of the previous one. when no **order by ** clause is given they default to order by id and the results are persistent on refresh. should I ask another question about this. thank you very much for your replies

Comment: I can't help you with php. Execute the query a few times without any limit and offset and check the results. If they are correct (I'm sure of that) then the issue must be in the php code.

Comment: I tried many times. still, the results are random. I will continue to search for a way to define relevance and order by it